# Freebase query with multiple unique child items

Tags: freebase, mql

Let's say I want to get all movies in which at least two (different) actors called "John" played:

[Example query](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor/?q=%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/film/film%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22limit%22:3,%22/film/film/initial_release_date%22%3a%221935%22,%22starring%22%3a%5B%7B%22a%3aactor%22%3a%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/film/actor%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22name~=%22%3a%22John%22%7D%5D,%22b%3aactor%22%3a%5B%7B%22type%22%3a%22/film/actor%22,%22name%22%3anull,%22name~=%22%3a%22John%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%5D&env=%7B%22extended%22:1%7D):

```
[{
  "type":"/film/film",
  "name":null,
  "limit":10,
  "/film/film/initial_release_date":"2005"
  "starring":[{
    "a:actor": [{
       "type": "/film/actor",
       "name": null,
       "name~=": "John",
    }],
    "b:actor": [{
       "type": "/film/actor",
       "name": null,
       "name~=": "John",
    }]
  }]
}]
```

If you run the example query, you will see that it will list movies with only one "John" in them. How can I fix my query to exclude these results with duplicated children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you'll have to do the filtering client-side; queries in MQL are "tree-like" in that one part of the query can't refer to another part rather than being a generic graph.

In this case, you could look for films which have more than one "John" acting in them; however, MQL doesn't allow you to filter on a derived property like "count", so the best you can do is to [reverse sort based on the count](http://tinyurl.com/akhr5d7) and then just stop processing as soon as you hit the first entry with "count": 1. However, that query times out if you remove the fixed 1935 release date (sorting in MQL kills performance), so you're probably stuck with just simple client-side filtering.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work wonderfully, I wasn't aware of the dot notation in `"sort": "-starring.count"`.

Comment: Results are somehow thin, I think it misses some results, but I don't think it it could be better, so I accept your answer :)

Comment: If you have an example of film you think that query should be finding but isn't, I can try to explain why it's not finding it and maybe even modify the query to catch it.

Comment: If you're looking for actors with a first name of John, you might want to further constrain your query to "^John *" or some such, but other than that I can't improve on Philip's suggestions.  It's likely that the data just isn't there.